# Like Button - When I return to the page from Facebook it is not "liked"

Tags: facebook

I click on I Like Button in my webpage. Well, on my Facebook Profile I ca see that I like it.

Now, when I click on this link from Facebook, it will open the "liked" page, but on the Like Button it is not "liked".

In fact, the link I Like is http://www.mywebsite.com/?ID=1.

The link opened from Facebook is http://www.mywebsite.com/?ID=1&fb_action_ids=4752322324997&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582 (so two different "location"). It adds some addictional parameters.

Why? And how can I fix it? My code (taken directly from facebook developer page) :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=25352352352";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place just after body

```
<div id="fb-root"></div

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxx";

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
<script>
```

appId= Put your application ID.

Application should not be in sandbox mode.

Also check in firefox for any Javascript error.

Place below the code where you want like button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Like button require Apps ID.

Comment: It is not a javascript fault! It makes two different links, that's why :) Try yourself...